# unknown attribute: password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I got the error " unknown attribute: password"  while logging into the app. It doesn't seem to save the password. I am new to rails, can anyone help me on this?

This is the message that I get while running the app. Here are is the code from model and control files. 
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in UsersController#create

### unknown attribute: password

I am trying to create a login/password web app. Getting the following error while running the app. 
undefined method `encrypt_pasword'
app/models/user.rb:32:in`password='
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:43:in `new'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:43:in`create'

Here is the code from control file.

```
require 'digest/sha2'
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity

  attr_accessible :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :hashed_password, :salt
  attr_accessor :name
  attr_accessor :salt

  validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  validates :password, :confirmation => true
  attr_accessor :password_confirmation
  attr_reader  :password

  validate :password_must_be_present

  def User.authenticate(name, password)
    if user = find_by_name(name)
      if user.hashed_password == encrypt_password(password, user.salt)
        user
      end
    end
  end

  def User.encrypt_password(password, salt)
    Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(password + "wibble" + salt)
  end
  # 'password' is a virtual attribute
  def password=(password)
    @password =password
    if password.present?
      generate_salt
      self.hashed_password =self.class.encrypt_password(password, salt)
    end
  end
  private

  def password_must_be_present
    errors.add(:password, "Missing password") unless hashed_password.present?
  end

  def generate_salt
    self.salt = self.object_id.to_s + rand.to_s
  end

end
```

Here is  my model file

```
require 'digest/sha2'
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity

  attr_accessible :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :hashed_password, :salt
  attr_accessor :name
  attr_accessor :salt
  attr_accessor :password

  validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  validates :password, :confirmation => true
  attr_accessor :password_confirmation
  attr_reader  :password

  validate :password_must_be_present

     def encrypt_password
         self.encrypted_password 
    end

       def User.authenticate(name, password)
    if user = find_by_name(name)
      if user.hashed_password == encrypt_password(password, user.salt)
        user
      end
    end
  end

  def User.encrypt_password(password, salt)
    Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(password + "wibble" + salt)
  end
  private 
    def encrypt_password
      self.salt = make_salt if new_record?
      self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
    end

  # 'password' is a virtual attribute
  def password=(password)
    @password =password
    if password.present?
      generate_salt
      self.hashed_password =self.class.encrypt_password(password, salt)
    end
  end

  private

  def password_must_be_present
    errors.add(:password, "Missing password") unless hashed_password.present?
  end

  def generate_salt
    self.salt = self.object_id.to_s + rand.to_s
  end

end
```

Comment: first off you can and should declare your class methods as either `def self.encrypt_password` or the more formal `class << self; def encrypt_password; end; end;`

next question is why is `encrypt_password` even a class method, can't it just be a private instance method?

Comment: Can you verify whether `User` indeed has the attribute `password`? An easy way to confirm this is to log into your Rails console from the command line by typing `rails console`, then typing `User`. This should bring up the User model and list all attributes associated with it.

Answer (score 2):

encrypt_pasword is missing an s.

Comment: yes I did correct the typo and added the encrypt_password class. Now I got the following error ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in UsersController#create

unknown attribute: password

Comment: well, that's obviously a new problem. please check in which line the error occurred (that's stated in the error message), and look at that line of code. If you don't know the problem then, you could post that info here, but without that, it's hard to help you.